# Empty screens for several pages in Artifactory after upgrade

Tags: artifactory

We are seeing  Empty screens for several pages in Artifactory . On checking the issue ,it seems we need to set artifactory.http.client.max.total.connections value. But I want to know its current default value . How do I find that ?

Comment: Which version of Artifactory? from which version did you upgrade? any errors in the log?

Comment: Upgraded to  4.12.2  ,error we see is :Client Closed Request 499: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe